# Copper losses in electrical machines

Tags: transformer

Why we take copper losses I^2 R and why not I^2 Z?
When we are measuring copper losses in transmission lines or generator motor or transformer we use above case  why we do so?

Comment: Hi and welcome to EE stack exchange! Please tell us a bit more on the 'background' of your question. Maybe draw a circuit of your problem to show us what you are thinking.

Comment: specifically, why you think you should be using Z instead of R, and what Z is. As Stefan said, we really don't know how to help you without a little more background.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If Z is the combined resistance and reactance, only the resistive part R will lead to losses. The reactive part only consumes reactive power

Comment: But reactive is also loss then why nit consider reactive loss only resistive loss is considered why?